# Bean Validation for POST requisition in JAX-RS with Jersey implementation

Tags: validation, http, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using the Jersey implementation for JAX-RS, and I was looking for an example where I can use the Bean Validation in POST requisitions. I have this operation, for example:

```
@POST
@Path("document/annotations/save")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Map<String, Object> saveAnnotation(
        @FormParam("user") String userStr,
        @FormParam("documentId") String documentId,
        @FormParam("documentPage") Integer documentPage,
        @FormParam("annotationContent") String annotationContent,
        @FormParam("annotationId") Long annotationId,
        @FormParam("isMobile") Boolean isMobile) { // the code... }
```

I wanna use validations constraints (`@NotNull`, `@Pattern`, etc) for each method param. I saw this [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/rest/latest/reference/en-US/html/rest.validation.html) where they're using the Seam Framework to do that.

Currently, I'm trying to use the `javax.validation` implementation to validate my requests, but it doesn't working.

Is there a way to use the JSR-303 specification with JAX-RS?

Tnks.

Comment: How about use aop like `AspectJ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible using Jersey; one possible alternative is to write a customer resource filter and bind to the `@NotNull`, etc. annotations.

It would be simpler if it was encapsulated in a resource class because you could then bind to a `@Valid` annotation on your method and validate the bean in one shot.

Because JSR-303 is designed to deal with beans and not a collection of parameters then it ends up being very verbose when you try to bend it to your will.

IMHO it's better not to keep validation inside your class anyway and to either use the pipes and filters pattern, i.e. `ContainerRequestFilter`, or to use something like AspectJ as @Willy suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. See docs for latest Jersey

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e9380

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html